# Что содержится в строке ? выводит пустоту

Tags: c++, c

Код:

```
char s = "some_text";
```

и как ее вывести?

```
  printf("%s", s);
```

Я пробовал использовать другие способы задания строки, но сейчас мне удобно использовать этот(наверное), да и узнать самому хочется как работать с подобной строкой.

Comment: `char` — это один символ. Но т.к. это также целочисленный тип, то здесь `char s = "some_text";` указатель на первый символ строки `"some_text"` преобразуется в целое число. Такое преобразование требует явного приведения типа, и приведённый код не должен компилироваться, но C компиляторы зачастую достаточно либеральны. Обычно тип `char` не способен вместить указатель, и результат преобразования не определён. Далее `printf` ожидает получить указатель `char*` но получает просто `char`. Поведение программы не предсказуемо. Заменить `char s` на `const char* s`.

Comment: Это не должно компилироваться. Если компилируется, значит настройки компилятора плохие.

Comment: Это компилируется с двумя предупреждениями которые ясно указывают на несоответствие типов при объявлении переменной и при её печати.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строки в Си это массив символов заканчивающийся терминальным нолём. Один char это один символ:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c = 'A';

    printf("Output: %c\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Создавать и выводить строку в Си можно таким способом:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Создаем массив символов с завершающим терминальным нолём '\0'
    char s[10] = "some_text";

    // Выводим строку в консоль
    printf("Output: %s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Или так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s[10] = {'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', '_', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', '\0'};

    printf("Output: %s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```